# Testing function signatures with ParameterTypeTuple

Tags: unit-testing, templates, metaprogramming, d

I'm writing a module with mixin templates to supply a `main` function for unit-testing purposes.  Usage is as follows:

```
/* For modules without their own main, e.g. libraries.
 * main is conditionally supplied using version(unittest).
 */
mixin Main;

/* For executable modules defining function "realMain".
 * Generated main has the same signature and return type
 * as realMain, and transfers control to it.  Additionally,
 * main exits without calling realMain for version (unittest).
 */
mixin Main!realMain;
```

The idea is that *every* module of mine mixes in `main` appropriately, so that:

- Libraries don't need `--main` passed to `rdmd`, because
- There seems no good way to decide *not* to pass `--main` for modules that define their own, when automatically running unit tests for every file in a directory hierarchy -- the exit code from `rdmd` is the same as for a failed compile.

I'm using `std.traits` to determine `realMain`'s validity as a `main` function, and ensure that my generated `main` has the same signature.  Everything seems to be working, but I think it could be cleaner.  Currently, my template for checking valid `main` arguments looks like this:

```
template isMainArgTypes(alias main)
{
    static if (is(ParameterTypeTuple!main == TypeTuple!()))
        enum isMainArgTypes = true;
    else static if (ParameterTypeTuple!main.length == 1
        && is(ParameterTypeTuple!main[0] T : const T[]))
    {
        enum isMainArgTypes = is(T : const char[]);
    }
    else
        enum isMainArgTypes = false;
}
```

I feel sure there must be some way to condense the middle condition into a single `is` expression, without explicitly testing the tuple length and separately checking for a string type, but so far my nascent metaprogramming-fu has fallen short.

Any ideas, D wizards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try comparing it to a function type:

```
enum isMainArgTypes = is(typeof(&main) == int function()) || 
                      is(typeof(&main) == void function()) || 
                      is(typeof(&main) == int function(string[])) || 
                      is(typeof(&main) == void function(string[]));
```

No shorter but it looks cleaner as it needs no `static if`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The advantage of not specifically testing for functions is that you can use other kinds of callable values, but I agree, this is cleaner. It also seems that the closest we have to examples of idiomatic D at the moment come from the Phobos source :)